# Get events from Google calendar and database to appear in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am trying to show events from entity database and from a public google calendar.

I have tried all of the options shown on Stack Overflow to no avail. I can get events to load on two different calendars on different pages using the examples on [google calendar example (github)](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/demos/google-calendar.html)
and [database example (youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jt9vSY802mM)

However I can not get them to load on the same calendar on a single html page. I am using an MVC5 app on vs 2017. 
I am just a hobbyist and not a qualified coder so any help much appreciated.

here's how I am getting the an event from the database:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var events = [];
    var selectedEvent = null;
    FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
    function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
        events = [];
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/home/ListEvents",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                    events.push({
                        eventID: v.EventID,
                        title: v.Subject,
                        description: v.Description,
                        start: moment(v.Start),
                        end: v.End != null ? moment(v.End) : null,
                        color: v.ThemeColor,
                        allDay: v.IsFullDay
                    });
                })

                GenerateCalender(events);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('failed');
            }
        })
    }
```

and here's how I am getting event from the database and Google (the following of the above code):

```
function GenerateCalender(events) {
    $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
    $('#calender').fullCalendar({
        contentHeight: 400,
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
        plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'list', 'googleCalendarPlugin'],
        header: {
            left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'listMonth,month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        eventLimit: true,
        eventColor: '#378006',
        eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
            element.find('#txtSubject');
            element.find('#txtSubject');
            element.find('.fc-list-item-title');
            element.find('.fc-list-item-title');
            //return ['all', event.conferencier].indexOf($('#filter-conferencier').val()) >= 0;
            return ['All events', event.title].indexOf($('#numero').val()) >= 0 || ['', event.color].indexOf($('#color').val()) >= 0;
        },
        googleCalendarApiKey: '*************************',
        eventSources: [
            events,
            {
                googleCalendarId:'blah...blah' 
            }
        ],
        eventClick: ETC ETC
    });
```

I also tried adding those lines:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=BLAH.......BLAH');
    }
})
```

Comment: Your addEventSource command would never work because the link you've pointed it to is the one for embedding a google-generated view of your events into your page - i.e. it will supply ready-made HTML rather than event data. Clearly you can't then add that to fullCalendar...it would only be useful to replace fullCalendar entirely. But it shouldn't be necessary anyway.

Comment: Also `plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'list', 'googleCalendarPlugin']` is only valid in fullCalendar version 4. But the rest of your code is using [version 3](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3#toc) . You can just remove this line. The GitHub example you've quoted is for version 4. But version 3 and version 4 are [very different](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3) and most code is incompatible between the versions. You need to choose a version and stick to it, and only rely on examples and documentation related to your chosen version.

Comment: Anyway it's unclear what exactly "not able to" means, specifically? What is the end result of the code above? Do you see _any_ events? Do you see events from one of the sources but not the other, perhaps? Or some other result? And do you know how to use your browser's Developer Tools (press F12 on most browsers to open them) to check for any errors which may be occurring in the code? It would be useful to know if you are seeing any. Whilst you haven't written the code in the most efficient way, it looks like it should basically work in theory.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/google-calendar shows you how to correctly specify a google calendar event source in version 3.

Comment: Another point...it's unclear what `return ['All events', event.title].indexOf($('#numero').val()) >= 0 || ['', event.color].indexOf($('#color').val()) >= 0;` is supposed to be doing? What's your intention here? It looks like it would filter your events based on whether an event's title and colour fields match values entered into other fields in your page...but it's unclear if you actually have those fields or not, or if they contain values which would match your data. If they don't, your events won't show. If you're not seeing events, try removing that line just for testing.

Comment: Next one: `element.find('#txtSubject');
            element.find('#txtSubject');
            element.find('.fc-list-item-title');
            element.find('.fc-list-item-title');` don't actually do anything productive...again not sure what the intent was here. You can just remove them, unless you're planning to change them somehow to do something useful in future?

Comment: And `defaultDate: new Date(),` is redundant, since fullCalendar will set today's date as the default date as standard. You're just re-specifying what is already the normal value. So again you can remove this line without changing the behaviour of the calendar. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/defaultDate for evidence.

Comment: Hi Adyson thanks for the replies. I suppose the key bit is "unable to" means I can get the events to show from gogle claendar if I use the google layout from fullcalendar or I can get the database events to show if I use another layout which I have created, but I cannot get google calendar events and database events to show on the same calendar, in either layout. So in (my layout) eventSources: if I comment out the googleCalendarId it shows the events from the database. if both sources are un-commented it shows nothing just the calendar. adding home/Events source to google layout shows nothing

Comment: Part 2 The bits of code you have mentioned later "return[All events" AND "element.find" relate to a search bar above the calendar which displays events filtered by words and/Or events filtered by colour. So if I type "diner" in the search bar it returns events with the word diner in the title. If I also select red from the drop down it will return events that are red and say diner. That seems to be working fine surprisingly. I couldn't find anywhere where it showed you how to search for events by word only to filter events so this uses the events Render command (if that's the right phrase).

Comment: Ok. So seems like the issue relates somehow to the Google events. Like I said earlier, have you checked for any errors in the Console when trying to use them? P.s. It's hard for me to test any of this since clearly I don't have (and don't want) your API key. All I can do is look at the code, which appears like it should work

Comment: Hi Adyson. I have gone through the console and negated most of the errors by removing the offending java scripts files (everything still working), the remaining errors are in jquery.min but if I remove that then my side nav doesn't work. Could there be something wrong in the function "FetchEventAndRenderCalendar" ??

Comment: Possibly. But I can't guess what your errors are. You'll need to show them in the question. Each error should have a stack trace too - i.e. a trail of function calls which led to the one which errored. So if you expand that you would be able to see if it originated in your code, and which line started it off